# Calculate price difference in matrix visual between 2 locations for a selected maturity - PowerBI Dektop

Tags: dax, powerbi-desktop

I am desperately trying to calculate the difference of price 'ProductValue' (from the Fact table) between 2 hub locations on a matrix visual. Basically I want to perform a A - B calculation with knowing that A is the based price (base in Germany "DE") and B represents a chosen hub location chosen from the '_dlv Zone-Hub' column in Dim Table. I want also to choose a specific maturity "Y+1-BL" or "Y+2-BL", etc, ... To picture the above described, here is what I am trying to operate:
[image: A-B]

I have tried to create a new measure with this DAX statement but it's not working:

```
DIFF =
CALCULATE(
SUM('Fact TblMarketPrice'[ProductValue]),
FILTER('Dim TblMarketProduct','Dim TblMarketProduct'[_Mat T ST] = SELECTEDVALUE('Dim TblMarketProduct'[_Mat T ST])
),
FILTER('Dim TblMarketProduct','Dim TblMarketProduct'[_dlv Zone-Hub] = "DE")
) -
CALCULATE(
SUM('Fact TblMarketPrice'[ProductValue]),
FILTER('Dim TblMarketProduct','Dim TblMarketProduct'[_Mat T ST] = SELECTEDVALUE('Dim TblMarketProduct'[_Mat T ST])
),
FILTER('Dim TblMarketProduct','Dim TblMarketProduct'[_dlv Zone-Hub] = SELECTEDVALUE('Dim TblMarketProduct'[_dlv Zone-Hub]))
)
```

Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you did not alter any interaction of your slicers that are filtering your A-B matrix.

```
DIFF =
    VAR _A = 
        CALCULATE(
             SUM('Fact TblMarketPrice'[ProductValue]),
             'Dim TblMarketProduct'[_dlv Zone-Hub] = "DE"
       )
   VAR _B = SUM('Fact TblMarketPrice'[ProductValue])
   RETURN
       _A - _B
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the suggestion did not work. It does not display the price difference but a negative price for the B values. It seems that A value is not taken into account.

Comment: You can check what _A is returning just by removing the _B subtraction. What measure are you using in your A table?

Comment: I am using the [ProductValue] measure

Comment: Returning just _A gives you what result? Are you sure you don't have other filters in place?